# new Java Generic class constructor issue when templete class nested

Tags: java, generic-programming

All

I have below define :

**JsonResponse.class** as below:

```
public abstract class JsonResponse<T> extends AbstractResponse {
private T jsonObject;

public JsonResponse(HttpResponse httpResponse, Class<T> classT) {
    super(httpResponse);
    jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(
            ResponseUtils.getStringContent(getHttpResponse()), classT);
}

public T getJsonObject() {
    return jsonObject;
}

}
```

But below class i want to new and return as:

```
return new JsonResponse<T>(response, classT);
```

but I can't compile it with error, would you please take a look at it . Thank you .

```
public class JsonResponseHandler<T> implements ResponseHandler<JsonResponse<T>> {

private Class<T> classT;

public JsonResponseHandler(Class<T> classT) {
    this.classT = classT;

}

@Override
public JsonResponse<T> handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    return new  JsonResponse<T>(response, classT) ; //compile  always error
}

}
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Eclipse no tipped error with Big Cross

Comment: What? Anyways, `JsonResponse` class is abstract. You can't instantiate it. That is where the error is.

Comment: It's so my mistake , I am so careless , Thank you very much , Because of this error , I even guess it can't supported by my design . Thank you again .

Comment: As a compute programmer , It is more quick than using Google to search related strange technology issue  that Using Stackoverflow to ask  .

Comment: @JerryCai It may be more convenient, but reading the compiler error would have clued you in relatively quickly as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
public JsonResponse<T> handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
    throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

return new  JsonResponse<T>(response, classT) ; //compile  always error
}
```

2 issues:

- `JsonResponse` is abstract.
- You're constantly redeclaring the genericism:

  ```
  public JsonResponse handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
  throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

      return new  JsonResponse(response, classT) ; //compile  always error
  }
  ```

It's already generic and should have reifiable type params.